# Is there a way to create traces dynamically for example for a stacked bar chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I have some code that I am working with:

These are traces to create a stacked bar chart. Now I am looking for a way to have these traces be dynamic depending on a variable that is fed by a dropdown menue.

The issue is that not all of the traces are needed for every selection in the dropdown menue. For example Selection A doesnt have values for "Residential" and this gives me an error.

```
  pv = pd.pivot_table(
        df_plot,
        index=['Year'],
        columns=["Market segment"],
        values=['Value'],
        aggfunc=sum,
        fill_value=0)

trace1 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[("Value", "Residential")], name="Residential")
trace2 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[("Value", "Business – small")], name="Business – small")
trace3 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[("Value", "Business – medium")], name="Business - medium")
trace4 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[("Value", "Business – micro")], name="Business - micro")
trace5 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[("Value", "Business – SME")], name="Business - SME")
trace6 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[("Value", "Business")], name="Business")


return {
    'data': [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5, trace6],
    'layout':
    go.Layout(
        title='Metric: {}'.format(Metric),
        barmode='stack')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add an if condition while preparing the trace and actually check if there is data in the pivot. If there is no data, we assign an empty object to the trace, please refer the below minimum working example, please let me know if this solves your issue!

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()

df_plot = df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])

pv = pd.pivot_table(
        df_plot,
        index=['A'],
        columns=["B"],
        values=['C'],
        aggfunc=sum,
        fill_value=0)

if 2 in list(pv.columns.levels[1]):
    trace1 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[("C", 2)], name="Two")
else:
    trace1 = {}
if 5 in list(pv.columns.levels[1]):
    trace2 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[("C", 5)], name="Five")
else:
    trace2 = {}

py_offline.iplot({
    'data': [trace1, trace2],
    'layout':
    go.Layout(
        barmode='stack')
})
```

Additional Details:

The result of the below pivot table code is.

```
pv = pd.pivot_table(
        df_plot,
        index=['A'],
        columns=["B"],
        values=['C'],
        aggfunc=sum,
        fill_value=0)
```

[image: pivot table result]

Thus when you do `pv.columns` we get the details of all the individual columns of the pivot table, which looks like below.

```
pv.columns
```

> MultiIndex(levels=[['C'], [2, 4, 6, 8]],
>              labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
>              names=[None, 'B'])

You can simply create a for loop to loop through the list of parameters array and apply the `if condition` validation explained in the previous example and finally plot it, please refer the below code and let me know if there is any issues.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()

df_plot = df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])

pv = pd.pivot_table(
        df_plot,
        index=['A'],
        columns=["B"],
        values=['C'],
        aggfunc=sum,
        fill_value=0)
arr = []
params = [{'name': "Two", 'val': 2},{'name': "Five", 'val': 5}]
for param in params:
    if param['val'] in list(pv.columns.levels[1]):
        temp = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[("C", param['val'])], name=param['name'])
    else:
        temp = {}
    arr.append(temp)
py_offline.iplot({
    'data': arr,
    'layout':
    go.Layout(
        barmode='stack')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will test this immediatly.

Comment: Muali I have been testing it and I have two questions if you have time to explain that would be great. 1. What exactly does the levels[1] command refer to? and my second question is : say I have a lot more traces maybe 10 or more, would there be an easy way to create a single loop that creates traces depending on the availability. Say if the trace values are stored in one column/variable.

Comment: @Tim Updated my answer, please do figure out the rest, you just need to play around with the code I provided